# Returning ID of inserted query in TypeORM and MySQL

Tags: typescript, typeorm

I,m new to TypeORM and I have problem that I'm trying to solve.
I'm wondering how to retrieve ID after INSERT query. 
I have column @PrimaryGeneratedColumn() with id number in my entity and my code looks similar to this:

```
await getConnection()
    .createQueryBuilder()
    .insert()
    .into(Test)
    .values([
        { firstName: "test", lastName: "test" }
     ])
    .execute();
```

What I want to archieve is to return ID of inserted row after executing this function.

EDIT: I'm using MySQL.

Is that possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can add `.returning("your_id_column_name")`

```
await getConnection()
    .createQueryBuilder()
    .insert()
    .into(Test)
    .values([
        { firstName: "test", lastName: "test" }
     ])
    .returning("your_id_column_name")
    .execute();
```

Comment: I tried that also but it is only supported by Microsoft SQL and PostgreSQL. I forget to mention that I'm using MySQL.

Comment: Did you try using different strategy for insert? such as `Test.save({ firstName: "test", lastName: "test" })`

Comment: Thanks for good idea. I didn't know that strategy and now when I used it, all is working as expected.

Comment: Typeorm have many different ways to implement the same functionality, checkout BaseEntity, EntityManager, EntityRepository, Connection.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
let test: Test = [{ firstName: "test", lastName: "test" }];
test = await getRepository(Test).insert(test).generatedMaps[0];
```

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
const testRepo = getRepository(Test)    
let insert = await testRepo()
           .createQueryBuilder()
           .insert()
           .into(Test)
           .values([
               { firstName: "test", lastName: "test" }
            ])
           .execute();
console.log("id: ",insert.raw.insertId);
```

after you will get an object with some properties, one of the properties is "raw" and inside "insertId".
in this case: insert.raw.inserId --> is the id of the insert.
P.D.: sorry for my English

Answer (score -1):

In case of mssql I was struggling to get the accepted answer working. Later figured out - in the returning("your_id_column_name") part, we need to rather provide returning("inserted.your_id_column_name") to get the inserted id column value. Note that in my case the id column was an identity column and decorated with PrimaryColumn and insert:false option from typeorm side.